# Fill NaN values in DataFrame with generic values

Tags: python, pandas

Using Python3.7 and the currently most updated version of Pandas.
I have a dataframe with the following datatypes: `[category, float, object(text)]`
all i want to do is fill NaN values for the entire dataframe at once.

What ive been doing on my own is going one-by-one through every single column (hundreds at a time) and grouping columnnames into lists organized by datatype.  Then setting that list of columns with `pd.astype(datatype)`. this was extremely tedious and inefficient, as i still continue to get back lots of errors. Ive been doing it this way for months, but now i have excel sheets with arbitrary data to read in, and considering the size of the dataframes im beginning to work with (+/-400k) its unrealistic to continue that way.

For the dtypes "category" and "object(text)", i want to fillna with the string 'empty'. And for float dtypes, i want to fillna with 0.0. At this point in my project, I am not yet interested in filling with mean/median values.

Ideally I would like to achieve this with something simple like:

`df.fillna_all({'float':0, 'category':'empty', 'object':'empty'})`

please help!

Comment: It would help to see a sample input and expected output as well as code to make a [mcve], since your description isn't entirely clear. That said, [select_dtypes()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) seems applicable

Comment: Ill edit the question to include your suggestions thanks. As far as i understand select_dtypes will only select columns that have previously been defined as a specific type. when i ran df.select_dtypes(include=['float64']).columns.tolist() no data was returned, even though clearly there are columns that are float value.

Comment: In that case, please provide more information about how you're currently setting the dtype, since otherwise it's really hard to know how to help. See also [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is exactly what you need:

**1)** To fill in the `categorical` variables with 'empty', you can do:

```
# Identify the columns in your df that are of type Object (i.e. categorical)
cat_vars = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtypes == 'O'] 

# Loop over them, and fill them with 'empty'
for col in df[cat_vars]:
    df[col].fillna('empty',inplace=True)
```

**2)** To fill in the `numerical` variables with 0.0, you can do:

```
# Identify the columns that are numeric, AND have at least 1 nan to be filled
num_vars = [x for x in dat.columns if dat[x].dtypes !='O' and dat[x].isnull() > 0] 

# Loop over them, and fill them with 0.0
for col in df[num_vars]:
    df[col].fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

For the future, if you are interested in filling the numeric variables with **mean** or **median**:

```
for col in df[num_vars]:
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(df[col].median()) # or replace with mean() for mean
```